# Basic usage of SQL group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

A very basic question if this can be done using `Group by` in SQL Server.

I have a table like this:

```
ID   Version
-------------
123  1
123  3
158  1
158  2
158  4
```

using `Group By ID, max(Version)` I get

```
ID    Version
--------------
123   3
158   4
```

I have an extended table with another column `value`, which is the interesting data:

```
ID   Version   Value
----------------------
123  1         abc
123  3         xyz
158  1         pq
158  2         je
158  4         kju
```

I want to retrieve

```
ID   Version   Value
----------------------
123  3         xyz
158  4         kju
```

I fail to get the value as shown above. Is this possible by using `Group By`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve that with an INNER JOIN with a SUBQUERY. I don't know your table names but lets call them VersionTable and VersionValueTable. So I would do this:

```
SELECT vt.ID, vt.Version, vvt.Value
FROM VersionValueTable vvt
   INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(Version)
               FROM VERSION
               GROUP BY ID) vt ON vt.ID = vvt.ID AND vt.Version = vvt.Version
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `group by` for this.  The most common approach is `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by version desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

There are a zillion other ways to do this.  If you are learning about window functions, the closest to the `group by` is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(verson) over (partition by id) as max_version
      from t
     ) t
where version = max_version;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare version of rows with Max-version that belongs to each row ID .
With a subquery you can find the subset of rows that have the same ID and get the maximum value of Version field. As you see in the following code :

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable t1
    WHERE t1.version = 
      (SELECT max(version) FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
```

To find a subset of records, that have the same id as the current row in main Select query , you can use a whereclause  ( WHERE t2.id = t1.id ) where t1 is alias for our table in main query and t2 is the alias for the table in subquery.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.